# Book where one of a group of time travelers stays in the past, lives out her life there

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a book in 2005 or so in which some young people, maybe university students, went back to the middle ages with some kind of time machine and somehow they got stuck there for a while. They had all kinds of adventures and had to figure out how to stay alive in those times. Most of them made it back to the time.machine and returned to the present but there was a girl.who fell in love there and decided to stay. I remember that at the end of the book, the others who came back found a grave and found her name on it too with dates of birth and death from that time period. I would really love to find out what this book is and reread it. Thank you for anyone who can help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice question, but you might be able to improve it by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit]ing any additional details you recall.

Comment: Eszter, you can see the way to accept an answer at the [tour].

Comment: I see another answer has already been accepted but the description also superficially fits the plot of Orson Scott Card's _Pastwatch_.

Answer (score 11):

I think you're looking for Michael Crichton's *[Timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_(novel))*

> In Corazon, Dan Baker and his wife are lost and driving through the Northern Arizona desert when they come across a man in his seventies with very little hair on his head but a sizeable beard. He looks like a priest. They pull over to help him, then take him to a hospital in Gallup, New Mexico. They learn that the man works at ITC and has unexplainable growth abnormalities in his blood vessels. The man dies twenty-four hours later.
>
> In the Dordogne (southwest) portion of France, Archeology Professor Edward Johnston leads a group of relatively young archaeologists as they study the fourteenth-century towns of Castelgard and La Roque. Professor Johnston travels to New Mexico because he has reason to believe ITC is guilty of foul play. During his absence, his students discover several disturbing sights, including the lens to Professor Johnston’s glasses and an inexplicable message from him.
>
> The students—Chris Hughes, Kate Erickson, and André Marek—search for Johnston by flying to ITC headquarters in New Mexico. They are joined by David Stern, a computer geek whom André trusts with his life.
>
> While there, ITC CEO Robert Doniger informs them that Professor Johnston has traveled to 1357 using their undisclosed quantum technology. The students decide to venture into the past to rescue the professor. Stern chooses to stay behind, realizing that time travel is probably terrible for one’s biology.

....

> The team waits for Stern, who remains in the present, to fix the machine’s launching pad so they can return. André chooses to stay in the fourteenth century. The rest of the team returns to 1999.
>
> Back in the present and in control of the time machine, the team condemns ITC CEO Doniger to travel back to 1348, which was the start of the Black Plague. Learning the extent of Doniger’s inhumanity during their travels, they feel this punishment is just.
>
> The novel concludes with an epilogue. Chris and Kate are now married and expecting their first child. While digging through a site one day, they come across the grave of André and Lady Claire. They are pleased to know the two led a happy life together.

Comment: Curse being two seconds too late...

Comment: Fastest gun. {blows smoke off of his typing fingers}

Comment: Oddly enough, it doesn't look this has been an accepted answer before...

Comment: The movie wasn't too bad, but book was better.

Comment: @ESZTERANDOR welcome to SF&F; verbal thanks are always appreciated, but since the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)